# Add shortcut to insert text/code in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

The title explains it fairly well, but I'll elaborate. How can I add a shortcut to insert a line of code whenever I'm typing? For example (and this is what I'd use it for): In Xcode 7, `println` was removed, and whenever I type `print` it adds `\n` after whatever I'm printing. I have to type `terminator: ""` to avoid this, but it gets repetitive and I would like a shortcut to insert that instead. I would ask for how to add to autocomplete but that would probably be too complicated for me. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds a LOT like the infamous [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=542341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Xcode's code snippet feature. A good place for details (including pictures) is: [Xcode Snippets - NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/).

Summary:

1. Type your `print` statement as you want it to autocomplete.
2. Open the Code Snippet Library from the Utilities Inspector, at the bottom
   ({}).
3. Select your `print` statement, and drag it to the Code Snippet Library.
4. Find your statement at the bottom of the list (named something like My Code Snippet).
5. Double-click the snippet name, and click Edit.
6. Fill in the info you want: name, description, etc. For the Completion Shortcut box, type `print`.
7. Click Done.

Now, whenever you type `print`, you'll see your shortcut in the completion list!

**Edit:** You can even insert a placeholder token like this:

`print("<# text #>", terminator: "")`

In this example, when you select to autocomplete with your snippet, the result will have the word `text` in an oval between the quotes, ready for you to fill in!

Comment: I added my snippet but it doesn't appear in the autocomplete menu. Any ideas? EDIT: I didn't add `print` to the completion shortcut. Now it works. Thanks!